# Solving a problem about measurable sets without using indicator functions

Tags: measure-theory

I'm beginning to learn measure theory, and I have the following problem:

> Let  $A_1,A_2,....A_n$ measurable sets and $r\in \Bbb{N}$. If for every $x\in{[0,1]}$, $x$ is in at least $r$ of this sets, show that there is at least one $A_i$ such $m(A_i)\geq r/n$, with $m$ the Lebesgue measure.

I want solve this problem without using indicator functions and integration, but it seems difficult.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is there a particular reason you would like to solve it without indicator functions and integration?

Comment: The problem is at the beginning of a book ,before the author talks about integration

Comment: But i think that this problem  is more a problem of combinations than  a problem of measure theory properly ,and i try to construct a disjoint class of sets using the original class removing parts

Comment: But i think that this problem is more a problem of combinations than a problem of measure theory properly ,and i try to construct a disjoint class of sets using the original class,translating the sets into the unit interval and removing common parts

Comment: This can be done much more elegantly with indicator functions and integration on simple functions. I tried to "inline" the definitions of these objects into a proof, but it got long and ugly. I recommend you continue reading until you understand these two concepts, and believe me, they aren't difficult. Try this exercise after that.